# Save Media Stream for playback

Tags: node.js, stream, rtmp, mediastream, node-media-server

I've setup a local RTMP media server with the [node-media-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server) library. It receives media-stream from [Streamlabs](https://streamlabs.com/). I can access it with the localhost link easily and it works without any issue.

```
const NodeMediaServer = require("node-media-server");

const config = {
  rtmp: {
    port: 1935,
    chunk_size: 60000,
    gop_cache: true,
    ping: 30,
    ping_timeout: 60,
  },
  http: {
    port: 8000,
    allow_origin: "*",
  },
};

var nms = new NodeMediaServer(config);
nms.run();
```

In this way I can only view the live stream. But what if I wanted to go back 10 seconds in the video? As the video is not stored, it is not possible. Is there any way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

To save files for playback you first need to install ffmpeg package using npm.
You can use this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg

Then add this in your config:

```
trans: {
            ffmpeg: ffmpeg_d.path,
            tasks: [
                {
                app: 'live',
                mp4: true,
                mp4Flags: '[movflags=frag_keyframe+empty_moov]',
                }
            ]
        }

 http: {
              port: 8020,
              webroot: './public',
              mediaroot: './media',
              allow_origin: '*'
            },
```

A media folder will be added in your root project where you will find streamed video file for playback use.

Comment: @ajit-kumar let me know if your problem still exists or accept the answer if it is solved, please.